# running browserstack-cypress run --sync ends up with ends up with Client network socket disconnected before secure TLS connection was established

Tags: cypress, browserstack

I am trying to use browserstack-cypress with parameter local

Below are my step

1. run browserstacklocal for linux with command

   ./BrowserStackLocal --key $BROWSERSTACK_ACCESS_KEY --local-identifier $LOCAL_IDENTIFIER --proxy-host $PROXY_HOST --proxy-port $PROXY_PORT --proxy-pass $PROXY_PASS --proxy-user $PROXY_USER --enable-logging-for-api --force-proxy --force-local --verbose 2 > /dev/null 2>&1 &
   - sleep 10
2. verified above step is successful so next is running browserstack-cypress with below option

browserstack-cypress run --sync --specs "${TEST_SPEC_PATH}" --key $BROWSERSTACK_ACCESS_KEY --cf $TEST_CONFIG_PATH --env TEST_USER_NAME=$UBSTEST_USER_NAME,TEST_USER_PASSWORD=$UBSTEST_USER_PASSWORD,BROWSERSTACK_USER=$BROWSERSTACK_USERNAME,BROWSERSTACK_KEY=$BROWSERSTACK_ACCESS_KEY --verbose 2

I have below in my browserstack.json

```
     {
"auth": {
"username": "username",
"access_key": "password",
},
"connection_settings": {
    "local": true,
    "local_identifier": "5C0E65F2D95C4E55A8DE465248A44E99"
  },

but step above ends up with below error
Got Error in binary downloading request Error: Client network socket disconnected before secure TLS connection was established
    at connResetException (internal/errors.js:604:14)
    at TLSSocket.onConnectEnd (_tls_wrap.js:1513:19)
    at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:417:28)
    at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:323:22)
    at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1204:12)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:84:21) {
  code: 'ECONNRESET',
  path: null,
  host: 'bstack-local-prod.s3.amazonaws.com',
  port: 443,
  localAddress: undefined
```

I am using node **v12.16.1** and npm **6.13.1**

Answer (score 1):

Same issue was raised before may be this helps https://github.com/browserstack/browserstack-cypress-cli/issues/126

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).